# htaccess to match subdomain in host variable

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm running a multisite wordpress installation with 13+ sites.

```
www.domain.com
www.domain.es
www.domain.it
and so on...
```

I must redirect the wp-admin folders for each domain to https://secure.domain.tld

Examples:

```
http://www.domain.com/wp-admin => https://secure.domain.com/wp-admin
http://www.domain.es/wp-admin => https://secure.domain.es/wp-admin
http://www.domain.it/wp-admin => https://secure.domain.it/wp-admin
```

Right now I'm using:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^wp-admin https://secure.domain.com/wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.es
RewriteRule ^wp-admin https://secure.domain.es/wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
```

It works.
But it sucks.
Is there any clean solution to not repeat this for each domain? Is there any variable matching possibile with the host?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex alternation. So for your given example you can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domain\.(com|es)$
RewriteRule ^wp-admin https://secure.domain.%1/wp-admin/ [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: But you're redirecting everything to https://secure.domain.com while you need to redirect on .com for .com domain and on .es for .es domain